# asp.net 4.5 model binding usercontrol within formview

Tags: model-binding, formview, asp.net-4.5

How can I bind usercontrol within formview. If I not use usercontrol everythings work fine , when I move to inputs in usercontrol model binding is not working.

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one as ascx control?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyGridView1.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyGridView1" %>

<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCustomers" PagerSettings-Position="Bottom"
    AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" PagerSettings-Visible="true"
    PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" Caption="MyGridViewControl"
    CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowModelStateErrors="true"
    ShowValidationErrors="true" />`
```

And add SelectMethod in code behind of the control. Register `<%@ Register Src="~/MyGridView1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyGridView1" %>` and use this control as `<uc1:mygridview1 runat="server" id="MyGridView1" />`

Comment: thanks for answer , but my scenario is different I have edit.aspx page and several usercontrol  within edit.aspx and  they are part of the whole.I wanted to take apart the entity